# Using Javascript to check If a page doesn't contain a certain word

Tags: javascript, search

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'WORD')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node==null)
```

This checks for a string.

Is there an opposite of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care only about the body innerHTML you can use this:

```
document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("theWord") === -1 // doesn't contain
```

Comment: What will happen if I change if (node==null) to if (node=null)?

Comment: @user713002, it will assign null to `node`, but how is it related to your question or to my answer?!